# Map Refresh in Infrastructure Map Server 2015

Tags: mapguide, autodesk

I have a MapGuide application build in MapGuide 2011 where I refreshed my map using the following script

```
function MapRefresh() {
       debugger;
       ExecuteMapAction(20);
        parent.parent.mapFrame.Refresh();

    }
```

Now I am upgrading my application to Autodesk Infrastructure Map Server 2015 where the above script does not work,
Please guide me as to how I can refresh my main map from a panel?